# Visual Studio Setup Project not updating Content File

Tags: installation, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Visual Studio Setup project which includes a .SQL file from my project which should always overwrite the existing file if I run the installer on the same machine to update to a new version. The problem is that doesn't always seem to happen. Under `File System > Application Folder > File Installation Properties`, which property would tell the installer to always overwrite the existing .SQL file on an install?

Answer (score 3):

The upgrade is an install of the new files on top of the older files, during which file overwrite rules are followed. The rule for data files is that they will not be overwritten if they've been updated since they were installed. If you've installed a database that's now full of customer data it's usually a bad idea to just replace it with a new empty database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/neither-file-has-a-version

Among the ways to solve your problem are:

1. Update the existing file with the new data using a custom action.
2. Avoid the problem in the first place by having the installed file copied to a location where it can be used, updated etc by the application. The original can then be overwritten by the upgrade, and the application detect that there is a new one to use, that it copies to replace the previous copy. It maybe too late for this.
3. Have the application make the creation date and modify date of the file have identical values so that the upgrade will think it's not been updated.
4. Install the new file to a different location (and use 1. from now on). The older file will be removed by the upgrade.
5. Edit the MSI file (with a tool like Orca) to move the location of RemovePreviousVersions (in the InstallExecuteSequence) so that it is immediately after InstallInitialize. This will completely remove all of the old files before installing the new ones, so it won't help if you have that database full of customer data mentioned in the opening paragraph.

Comment: Could he exploit the "bug" in MSI whereby modified files are happily uninstalled and then reinstalled in their original form by using an early REP setting? That doesn't work in Visual Studio Installer Projects?